# What are the commands for FFmpeg extract images binary command

Tags: android, ffmpeg

**My ffmpeg for android studio is compiled using this:**

> compile 'com.writingminds:FFmpegAndroid:0.3.2'

**In the code below i have this line of code:**

> String[] complexCommand = {"-i", yourRealPath, "-c:v", "libx264",
>   "-crf", "22", "-map", "0", "-segment_time", "6", "-g", "9",
>   "-sc_threshold", "0", "-force_key_frames", "expr:gte(t,n_forced*6)",
>   "-f", "segment", dest.getAbsolutePath()};

**Things i want to know:**

1. I'd like to know what those inputs(i.e. "-sc_threshold", "-g", "-crf") are, and what are their functions.
2. If a video has 30fps and is 5 seconds long, are there 150 frames, if so is ffmpeg able to extact all 150?

**This is my code:**

```
     /**
     * Command for extracting images from video
     */
    private void extractImagesVideo(int startMs, int endMs) {
        File moviesDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                Environment.DIRECTORY_PICTURES
        );

        String filePrefix = "extract_picture";
        String fileExtn = ".jpg";
        String yourRealPath = getPath(MainActivity.this, selectedVideoUri);

        File dir = new File(moviesDir, "VideoEditor");
        int fileNo = 0;
        while (dir.exists()) {
            fileNo++;
            dir = new File(moviesDir, "VideoEditor" + fileNo);

        }
        dir.mkdir();
        filePath = dir.getAbsolutePath();
        File dest = new File(dir, filePrefix + "%03d" + fileExtn);


        Log.d(TAG, "startTrim: src: " + yourRealPath);
        Log.d(TAG, "startTrim: dest: " + dest.getAbsolutePath());

        String[] complexCommand = {"-y", "-i", yourRealPath, "-an", "-r", "1/2", "-ss", "" + startMs / 1000, "-t", "" + (endMs - startMs) / 1000, dest.getAbsolutePath()};

        execFFmpegBinary(complexCommand);

    }

 /**
     * Executing ffmpeg binary
     */
    private void execFFmpegBinary(final String[] command) {
        try {
            ffmpeg.execute(command, new ExecuteBinaryResponseHandler() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(String s) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "FAILED with output : " + s);
                }

                @Override
                public void onSuccess(String s) {
                    Log.d(TAG, "SUCCESS with output : " + s);
                    if (choice == 1 || choice == 2 || choice == 5 || choice == 6 || choice == 7) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PreviewActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra(FILEPATH, filePath);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else if (choice == 3) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PreviewImageActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra(FILEPATH, filePath);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else if (choice == 4) {
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, AudioPreviewActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra(FILEPATH, filePath);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    } else if (choice == 8) {
                        choice = 9;
                        reverseVideoCommand();
                    } else if (Arrays.equals(command, lastReverseCommand)) {
                        choice = 10;
                        concatVideoCommand();
                    } else if (choice == 10) {
                        File moviesDir = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(
                                Environment.DIRECTORY_MOVIES
                        );
                        File destDir = new File(moviesDir, ".VideoPartsReverse");
                        File dir = new File(moviesDir, ".VideoSplit");
                        if (dir.exists())
                            deleteDir(dir);
                        if (destDir.exists())
                            deleteDir(destDir);
                        choice = 11;
                        Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, PreviewActivity.class);
                        intent.putExtra(FILEPATH, filePath);
                        startActivity(intent);
                    }
                }
```

**Code downloaded from:**

https://github.com/bhuvnesh123/FFmpeg-Video-Editor-Android

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1.**

> -sc_threshold : It is the scene change sensitvity (range between 0 - 100). At every scene change , a new I-frame is inserted.
>
> -g : It is GOP(Group of Pictures).Frame length interval. GOP determines maximum distance between I-frames.  Bonus tips : High GOP
>   makes video very effecient compression. Recommended value is 250
>
> -crf : Constant Rate Factor(CRF) defines a average desired quality instead of target bitrate.

**2.**

Yes , It is possible to fetch each frames recorded so far in video container using FFMPEG libs.

Bonus : `ffmpeg -i video.avi IMG%03d.jpg` - sample command to fetch each frame and convert that as a jpg image file and store it in same location.

Comment: simple FFMPEG application developed using C++. https://github.com/abdullahfarwees/screen-recorder-ffmpeg-cpp

Comment: https://www.ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-codecs.html check this links for FFMPEG global options. Also this tutorial ( http://dranger.com/ffmpeg/tutorial01.html ) demonstrates the fetching of all frames from video container using FFMPEG and storing in .ppm image format. comment below for any doubts clarification.